# Syntax error, unrecognized expression in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, prettyphoto

I have been using this PrettyPhoto code:

```
jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto'").prettyPhoto({overlay_gallery: false, social_tools:false, hook: 'data-gal'});
```

And it is working fine on all browsers except Safari which throws an

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto'

Do you have an advice or an idea of what Safari doesn't like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are missing `]` in `jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto'")` selector.

```
jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({overlay_gallery: false, social_tools:false, hook: 'data-gal'});
```

Comment: I can't believe chrome and firefox didn't throw an error for that... Thank you so much... I did this after 20 hours of coding. Fresh eyes for the win.

Comment: Got the very same problem here, but it worked in Chrome and Firefox. Sometimes it's a bad idea (of browser vendors) to "auto-correct" typos like that... I thought the times of testing your webpage in 20 different browsers is over... (Ironically, jquery's mission is to solve exactly that ;))